# Unable to correctly retrieve API objects

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I recently started using the @nuxtjs/strapi package with Strapi 4 and Nuxt 3. I find this module lacking in documentation as I'm not sure how to retrieve the information from my API. Here's what I've done so far:

```
const { find } = useStrapi()
const url = useStrapiUrl();
let kitUrl = '';
const { data, pending, refresh, error } = await useAsyncData(
    'home-page',
    () => find('home-page', { populate: ['kit_de_presse'] })
)
const response = data?.value?.data;
kitUrl = url + response?.attributes;
```

A number of problems arise:
The first is that every time I reload a page, I get an undefined, unlike if I modify the code and vite let a hot reload take place.
The second is that I'm retrieving a complex "RefImpl" object, as opposed to calling find() on its own without usingAsyncData().

How am I supposed to retrieve my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using useFetch or useAsyncData with Nuxt, the request is executed both server-side and client-side. My application called an API on localhost which ran on a Docker container, just like my application. When the client calls the API, everything works, since the container port is shared with my host machine. But when the server calls it, it calls it from inside its container, so localhost is itself. The solution was to create a custom network on the docker-compose and to check before making the request on which URL to make it:

docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  Strapi:
    driver: bridge
```

Create a new custom function on Nuxt app:

```
export async function fetchStrapiUrl(url: string) {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    const strapiBaseUri = process.server ? "http://strapi:1337/api" : runtimeConfig.public.strapiBaseUri + '/api';
    const res = await fetch(strapiBaseUri + url);
    return await res.json();
}
```

nuxt.config.ts:

```
runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            strapiBaseUri: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https://preprod.redacted.com:1338" : "http://localhost:1337"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't even need to use `useAsyncData`. There is documentation here: https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/usage#find. You can you it like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Restaurant } from '~/types'

const { find } = useStrapi()

const response = await find<Restaurant>('restaurants')
</script>
```

As for the issue with page reload, that probably happens because server can't fetch data for some reason. So it generates `undefined`, but then client refetches data. Are you using Strapi on `localhost` or on remote server?

Comment: According to the documentation, to take full advantage of SSR, useAsyncData. That's why I use this. I'm currently testing it on my localhost
https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/advanced

Comment: Can you check what is rendered on the server? You can curl to do this.

My assumption is that there is an error when server tries to make a request. I had this issue because Node 18 didn't resolve `localhost` properly. When I switched to Node 16, the issue was gone.

Comment: Indeed, it was the same kind of problem, useAsyncData makes the request on the server AND client side except that my api doesn't have the same url depending on the context. cf. my answer below